# Is it more efficient to create a variable for an element or select it each time?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Lets say I'm going to be targeting an element lots of times, which is more efficient?

Example 1:

```
var el = $("#element");
el.html("foo");
el.html("bar");
```

Example 2:

```
$("#element").html("foo");
$("#element").html("bar");
```

Or is there no difference at all?

Comment: First one will be a little more efficient but nothing you should never notice

Comment: @A.Wolff That's a double negative. I think you mean "Nothing you should ever notice". And you wouldn't, but your users might.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch not really

Comment: @AlonGubkin Depends on how many times you're doing it, and how old the user's browser/computer is... doesn't it?

Comment: It would be even more effecient to not save a var and do (if you do not reuse object) `$("#element").html("foo").html("bar");`

Comment: The example given is particularly bad, as it would be most efficient to skip `.html('foo')` as you're immediately overriding it with `.html('bar')`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch thx that's it: "Nothing you should ever notice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example 1 is more efficient, because you're only calling `$()` once and reusing the same object for subsequent calls to `.html()`.

It doesn't result in significant numbers, but if you know you are going to be interacting with the same element (or set of elements) then it's obviously redundant to call it each time.

Answer (score 2):

In most cases you can chain methods:

```
$('#element')
    .html('foo')
    .html('bar')
```

This way you gain both performance and readability.

Comment: This too. It does depend on the methods - not all of them are chainable and you'll have to read the documentation to find out which ones are and which are not.

Answer (score 1):

The first example is more efficient; and directly listed in [jQuery Performance Rules](http://www.artzstudio.com/2009/04/jquery-performance-rules/#cache-jquery-objects);
It's Rule 3 - Cache jQuery Objects.

Answer (score 1):

I know there are other answers here already but example 1 is more efficient and you should definitely use it starting now rather than later.

The reason that there is very little difference in performance in your example is because your selector has the highest DOM specificity possible. There is only supposed to be one use of an ID on any HTML page EVER. Even if you physically write the same ID twice, jQuery will only target the first instance.

If you were to do something a little more complex such as this:

```
$('form').find('input[type="text"]').filter(function(index){
    return $(this).css('color') == 'green';
}).somePlugin();

$('form').find('input[type="text"]').filter(function(index){
    return $(this).css('color') == 'green';
}).anotherPlugin();
```

Then it is much more worth it to cache it for better performance like this:

```
var target = $('form').find('input[type="text"]').filter(function(index){
    return $(this).css('color') == 'green';
});

target.somePlugin();
target.anotherPlugin();
```

Comment: ya caching is really efficient for selector returning big set of matched elements. This is really an important point IMHO, which makes your answer not redundant compare to other answers here